# AttributeError: 'PhysicsInformedNN1' object has no attribute 'train'

Tags: attributeerror

I try to implement PINNs in pytorch but I received this message

the code:

model = PhysicsInformedNN1(x0, u0, x1, layers, dt,lb, ub,q )

model.train(10000)

U1_pred = model.predict(x_star)

error = np.linalg.norm(U1_pred[:,-1] - Exact[idx_t1,:], 2)/np.linalg.norm(Exact[idx_t1,:], 2)
print('Error: %e' % (error))
How cam I fixed?

## the physics-guided neural network

class PhysicsInformedNN1():
def **init**(self, x0, u0, x1, layers, dt,lb, ub, q):

```
    # boundary conditions
    self.lb = torch.tensor(lb).float().to(device)
    
    self.ub = torch.tensor(ub).float().to(device)
    
    
    #data
    self.x0 = torch.tensor(x0).float().to(device)
    
    self.x1 = torch.tensor(x1).float().to(device)
    
    self.u0 = torch.tensor(u0).float().to(device)
    
    self.layers = layers
    self.q = q
    self.dt = dt
    # Create a dummy tensor for forward gradients with shape (N, self.q)
    self.dummy_x0_torch = torch.tensor(self.q).float().to(device)
    self.dummy_x0_torch= self.dummy_x0_torch.detach().clone()
     ##

    # Create another dummy tensor for forward gradients with shape (N, self.q+1)
    self.dummy_x1_torch = torch.tensor(self.q+1).float().to(device)
    self.dummy_x1_torch= self.dummy_x1_torch.detach().clone() ###
    
  
    
    # deep neural networks
    self.dnn = DNN(layers).to(device)
    
    # Load the data from the text file as a NumPy array
    tmp = np.float32(np.loadtxt('/content/Butcher_IRK100 2.txt', ndmin=2))
    # Convert the NumPy array to a PyTorch tensor

    #Reshape the first part of the tensor to get the IRK weights
    self.IRK_weights = torch.tensor(np.reshape(tmp[0:q**2+q],(q+1, q)))
    
    # Get the IRK times from the remaining part of the tensor
    self.IRK_times =torch.tensor(tmp[q**2+q:])
    
    # optimizers: using the same settings
    self.optimizer = torch.optim.LBFGS(
        self.dnn.parameters(), 
        lr=1.0, 
        max_iter=50000, 
        max_eval=50000, 
        history_size=50,
        tolerance_grad=1e-5, 
        tolerance_change=1.0 * np.finfo(float).eps,
        line_search_fn="strong_wolfe"       # can be "strong_wolfe"
    )

    self.iter = 0
    
    def fwd_gradients_0(self, U, x): 
        # Compute the gradients of U with respect to x
        g = torch.autograd.grad(U, x, grad_outputs=self.dummy_x0_torch, create_graph=True)[0]

        # Compute and return the gradients of g with respect to x (which are the second derivatives of U with respect to x)
        return torch.autograd.grad(g, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(g))[0]
    
    def fwd_gradients_1(self, U, x): 
        # Compute the gradients of U with respect to x
        g = torch.autograd.grad(U, x, grad_outputs=self.dummy_x1_torch, create_graph=True)[0]

        # Compute and return the gradients of g with respect to x (which are the second derivatives of U with respect to x)
        return torch.autograd.grad(g, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(g))[0]
        
    
    def net_U0(self, x):
        nu = 0.01 / np.pi
        
        # Apply the neural network to get U1
        U1 = self.neural_net(x)
        
        # Get U from U1 and compute the gradients
        U = U1[:, :-1]
        U_x = self.fwd_gradients_0(U, x)
        U_xx = self.fwd_gradients_0(U_x, x)
        
        # Compute the function F using U and its gradients
        F = -U * U_x + nu * U_xx
        
        # Compute U0 using matrix multiplication with IRK weights
        # The IRK weights should be a tensor of shape (q+1, q) and self.dt a scalar
        U0 = U1 - self.dt * torch.matmul(F, self.IRK_weights.T)
        
        return U0
    
    def net_U1(self, x):
        U1 = self.neural_net(x)
        return U1  # Output shape: N x (q+1)
    
    
    
    def loss_func(self):
        self.dummy_x0 = torch.ones((self.x0.shape[0], self.q), requires_grad=True)
        self.dummy_x0_torch= self.dummy_x0_torch.detach().clone()
        self.dummy_x1 = torch.ones((self.x1.shape[0], self.q+1), requires_grad=True)
        self.dummy_x1_torch= self.dummy_x1_torch.detach().clone()
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        self.U0_pred = self.net_U0(self.x0) # N x (q+1)
        self.U1_pred = self.net_U1(self.x1) # N1 x (q+1)
        

        loss = torch.sum((self.u0 - self.U0_pred) ** 2) + torch.sum(self.U1_pred ** 2)

        loss.backward()
        self.iter += 1
        if self.iter % 100 == 0:
            print('Iter %d, Loss: %.5e' % (self.iter, loss.item()))
        return loss
    
    def train(self):
       self.dnn.train()
            
       # Backward and optimize
       self.optimizer.step(self.loss_func)
      
      
    
        # Updating the model parameters
      
    def predict(self, x_star):
        # Assuming x_star is a PyTorch tensor that has been properly preprocessed if necessary.
        # Also assuming that self.U1_pred is a method that represents the forward pass of your PyTorch model.
        #x_star= torch.tensor(x, requires_grad=True).float().to(device)
        # Set the model to evaluation mode. This is important for layers like dropout or batchnorm.
        self.dnn.eval()
        # No need to track gradients here since we're only predicting, not training.
        with torch.no_grad(): ##
            U1_star = self.U1_pred(x_star)
            U1_star= U1_star.detach().cpu().numpy()
        return U1_star
```